# How do you define the path which CKEditor uses to search for config / language files?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

CKEditor seems to look for its configuration files relative to the location it was loaded from, not the location of ckeditor.js.  So loading CKEditor on the page http://www.example.com/articles/1 causes it to look for the language files in http://www.example.com/articles/1/lang/

The config file contains an attribute for baseHref, but it doesn't affect the editor resources themselves.

How do I set the path which CKEditor uses for its own resources?

Comment: I'm hitting this same problem - what did you do to fix it?

Comment: +1 i need to set the customConfig  and can't figure out the proper syntax or where to do so.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

That behavior that you describe isn't normal, for some reason CKEditor isn't identifying properly its own folder so you should set a `CKEDITOR_BASEPATH` variable before loading CKEditor.

It's briefly commented here: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html#.basePath but there might be other places where it's explained better.

A successful implementation is therefore:

```
<script>
  window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = 'http://example.com/path/to/libs/ckeditor/';
</script>
```

*Then* load the main `ckeditor.js` script. Note you can use root-relative paths e.g. `/path/to/libs/ckeditor/` but relative paths do not work.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!
(just an update, setting, CKEDITOR.basePath... causes issue when clicking 'specialChar'; Above solution fixed it)