# How to manually set the script path of ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

Usually we just need to unzip the package from the ckeditor website to a dictionary and use it like `CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');`. But my problem is the ckeditor cannot correctly recognize the path to the plugin and other files, makes the editor fail to load.

Is there any way to manually set the path to its files?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
I have tried to set the `CKEDITOR.basePath`, the editor loaded successfully, but the plugin don't works, exception
`[CKEDITOR.dialog.openDialog] Dialog "paste" failed when loading definition.`
The problem still remains

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you define the path which CKEditor uses to search for config / language files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807029/how-do-you-define-the-path-which-ckeditor-uses-to-search-for-config-language-f)

Comment: I had the same problem. Setting `window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH` **before** you load the actual ckeditor javascript file worked. Take a look at [this](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html#.basePath).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is old, but setting `CKEDITOR.plugins.basePath` should fix your problem.

Comment: I'm having this issue, but this didn't work for me. The pastetext plugin keeps loading /clipboard/dialogs/paste.js from the relative path, not from the CKEDITOR.plugins.basePath

Comment: `CKEDITOR.plugins.basePath` was replaced with everything using the `CKEDITOR.basePath` (c/o CKEDITOR_BASEPATH) to make things simpler.