# CKEditor missing/incorrect basePath in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor

In a custom module, I've included CKEditor

```
drupal_add_js( 'sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/ckeditor.js',array('weight'=>JS_LIBRARY+1));
drupal_add_js( 'sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js',array('weight'=>JS_LIBRARY+2));
```

And in my JS I'm now creating an instance on a textarea using

```
jQuery('#myTextArea').ckeditor();
```

**This was working, but now isn't.** Looking in Firebug, I see that ckeditor is trying to access **config.js**, and that it's looking for this at the URL of the page. It **should** be looking to http://example.com/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/.

I can't think what's changed recently that might have broken it!

I've tried passing config `{ basePath: '/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/' }` into the `ckeditor()` call but this is ignored, probably can't set this at runtime?

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong, or if this is a bug, is there a work around?

Comment: Think it's a bug in Drupal WYSIWYG https://drupal.org/node/1829534

Comment: ...but the patch on that bug report didn't fix it...

Comment: It works when Drupal's JS aggregation is not turned on. i.e. turn on js aggregation and the problem exhibits, turn it off and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, this seems to be to do with when the editor is loaded via Drupal's JS aggregation

Here is an ugly hack that it worked for me.

Edit the sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/ckeditor.js file and before the compressed js code add:

```
window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = 'http://example.com/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/';
```

Then just remember to do that every time you upgrade.

PS. Credit on [basepath hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807029/how-do-you-define-the-path-which-ckeditor-uses-to-search-for-config-language-f).

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor (tested 4.4.4) has a problem determining the correct base path, when you change the default ckeditor.js filename. For example, when you add a cachebreaker for live deployment or use an aggregated name.

You can easily reproduce that behavior, with the output of the property: CKEDITOR.basePath

Your are on a website (assume http://example.de) with the path /a/b/c/d, using the original ckeditor filename /ext/ckeditor/ckeditor.js:

```
Website: http://example.de/a/b/c/d
CKeditor: http://example.de/ext/ckeditor/ckeditor.js

console.log(CKEDITOR.basePath); //output: http://example.de/ext/ckeditor/
```

You are on the same website, same path and ckeditor.js changed:

```
Website: http://example.de/a/b/c/d
CKeditor: http://example.de/ext/ckeditor/ckeditor-whatever.js

console.log(CKEDITOR.basePath); //output: http://example.de/a/b/c/
```

Typically the JavaScript Console shows errors like:

```
Line 1: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'dir' of undefined
```

Therefore it is always necessary to set the base path, if you change the default filename ckeditor.js.