# ckeditor stopped showing up suddenly in php website. Displays plain textarea instead

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor, textarea, wysiwyg

There is a site which was working fine till a few days back. Its coded in PHP and has CKEditor as WYSIWYG editor integrated in the Admin panel pages, to update content.

However, since a few days, it only displays as a plain textarea instead of CKEditor (WYSIWYG interface). I checked the code, it seems all fine. Files and their Path references seems fine as well.

Could it be the PHP version upgrade or some server side update caused this issue? Here is my code below used for displaying the ckeditor (applying to textarea)

```
<textarea id="pbody" name="pbody" class="ckeditor"></textarea>
                        <?php
    // Include CKEditor class.
    include_once "../ckeditor/ckeditor.php";
    include_once '../ckfinder/ckfinder.php' ;

    // Create class instance.
    $CKEditor = new CKEditor();
    // Path to CKEditor directory, ideally instead of relative dir, use an absolute path:
    // If not set, CKEditor will try to detect the correct path.
    $CKEditor->basePath = '../ckeditor/';

    $ckfinder = new CKFinder();

$ckfinder->BasePath = '../ckfinder/';

// Note: the BasePath property in the CKFinder class starts with a capital letter.

$ckfinder->SetupCKEditorObject($CKEditor);

    // Replace textarea with id (or name) "editor1".
    $CKEditor->replace("pbody");
    ?>
```

Comment: Maybe check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807029/how-do-you-define-the-path-which-ckeditor-uses-to-search-for-config-language-f

Comment: Check out browser console. There may be an error.